# On Android, how can I build a Realm Adapter from a Realm List?

Tags: android, listadapter, realm

I'm writing a recipe app on Android using Realm.  I have a RealmList of type Ingredient in each Recipe object.  The object creation code is working fine.

Now I'm writing the code for the Fragment that displays a single recipe.  I was able to create a Realm Adapter for the all recipe titles list, since I built that list using a query like so:

```
public class RecipeTitleAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<RecipeTitle> implements ListAdapter {

    public RecipeTitleAdapter(Context context, int resId,
                 RealmResults<RecipeTitle> realmResults,
                 boolean automaticUpdate) { 
    ...

recipeTitles = RecipeTitle.returnAllRecipeTitles(realm);
final RecipeTitleAdapter adapter = new RecipeTitleAdapter(RecipeParserApplication.appContext, R.id.recipe_list_view, recipeTitles, true);
```

But now that I'm looking at the ingredients for a single recipe, I have a RealmList of Ingredients and not a RealmResults object.  My ingredient adapter class has the same type of constructor as the recipe titles adapter, so I want to know how (or even if) I can make it work starting with a RealmList.

```
public class IngredientAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Ingredient> implements ListAdapter {

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView quantity;
    TextView unitOfMeasure;
    TextView ingredientItemName;
    TextView processingInstructions;
}

public IngredientAdapter(Context context, int resId,
                          RealmResults<Ingredient> realmResults,
                          boolean automaticUpdate) {
....

final IngredientAdapter adapter = new IngredientAdapter(RecipeParserApplication.appContext, R.id.ingredientListView, recipe.getIngredients(), true);

public RealmList<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}
```

Since recipe.getIngredients returns a RealmList, the line where the IngredientAdapter is assigned returns a compile error:

Error:(63, 43) error: constructor IngredientAdapter in class IngredientAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,int,RealmResults,boolean
found: Context,int,RealmList,boolean
reason: actual argument RealmList cannot be converted to RealmResults by method invocation conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RealmList behaves like an normal array, so if you cannot make a query that matches what you want to display, you can just use any of the normal adapters like e.g. a ArrayAdapter. The only advantage of using a RealmBaseAdapter is that it autorefreshes, but that is fairly easy to accomplish yourself:

```
// Pseudo code
ArrayAdapter adapter;
RealmChangeListener listener = new RealmChangeListener() {
  public void onChange() {
    if (adapter != null) {
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ... 
  realm.addChangeListener(listener);
  RealmList data = getRealmListData();
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(data);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Does onChange get called for every change to the Realm? That is, even if the RealmList I'm looking at isn't affected the onChange will get called? That seems to be the case since we're adding the Change Listener to the entire Realm instead of just the RealmList.

Comment: yes! for a given realm on change will fire for all listeners. if this is a problem do well to use different realms for your  models if they have no relationship...         you can get a new realm creating new RealmModule or by doing Realm.getInstance(File folder). an many other ways.. check the docs